# How to avoid the change of index position while copying/cloning the array to new array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, content-management-system

I am fetching the data from CMS and the data is coming in the form of array. I am trying to copy/clone the array into a new empty array. My code snippet:

```
                .then((result) => {
                  console.log("header", result);
                  result.items.forEach((item) => {
                    this.check.push(item);
                  });
                });
```

When I see the console **console.log("header", result)** for this, I am getting data, but every time when I refresh the page the sequence of the content get changed. Due to that I am not able to  call API based on index position.

Please help me in this regard.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "Due to that I am not able to call API based on index position"?

Comment: If the data you get is always in order, your code should work fine. However, if the data you get is not always in order, you need to do some sorting for the data before you store it.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is not multidimensional you can try to use spread operator and do shallow copy e.g: this.check = [...result]. Furthermore, I would not suggest calling API's based on array index. It is not secure and you never know when will indexes be changed for some reason in the future. If you have object inside array use .find by object value and call your API's by that.